# Hide/show toggle on hover with fade in css

Tags: html, css, toggle

I have this simple hide/show `toggle` which fades in/out text when hovering. The only problem is, I don't want it to be invisble (because it takes up unnecessary space). But when I add display element the fade function doesn't work anymore.

```css
#stuff {
  opacity: 0.0;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
}

#hover {
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', FontAwesome;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#hover:hover+#stuff {
  opacity: 1.0;
  display: inline-block;
}

`
```

```html
<div id="hover">HOVER HERE</div>
<div id="stuff">Revealed text</div>
```

WITH FADE ANIMATION, but just hidden: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgg1u55s/)

WITHOUT FADE ANIMATION, but appears when hovering and doesn't take up space [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfjksbma/)

Is it possible to maintain the fade animation without the text just being invisible?

Comment: You can't animate the `display` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max-height` to remove the unwanted space

**See code snippet bellow:**

```css
#stuff {
  opacity: 0.0;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  max-height:0;
}

#hover {
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', FontAwesome;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#hover:hover+#stuff {
  opacity: 1.0;
  max-height:100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="hover">HOVER HERE</div>
<div id="stuff">Revealed text</div>
```

And if you want it to always take no space, you can use absolute position to make go out of the flow of the document

**See code snippet:**

```css
#stuff {
  opacity: 0.0;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  position:absolute;
}

#hover {
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', FontAwesome;
  font-weight: 600;
  
}
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
}
#hover:hover + #stuff {
  opacity: 1.0;   
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="hover">HOVER HERE</div>
<div id="stuff">Revealed text</div>
<div>
```

Comment: I used the max-height version now, and it works as a charm. As I'm going to get more "revealed text" later, I will use your second option for that. (Right now it gave me some position issues for "HOVER ME" )

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap your divs in another box and then absolutely position your hidden text so it doesn't take up any space - comments in code to explain what is happening

```css
/* add a container */
.container {
  position: relative;
}

#stuff {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;

  /* position stuff underneath the container */
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;

  /* give the background a colour so you can't see anything below */
  background: #ffffff;
}

#hover {
  width: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', FontAwesome;
  font-weight: 600;
}

/* show stuff on hover of the container - so you can hover the stuff without it dissappearing */
.container:hover #stuff {
  opacity: 1;
}

`
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="hover">HOVER HERE</div>
  <div id="stuff">Revealed text</div>
</div>
Some content below
```